# Showing dimension of a model in FreeCAD

Tags: freecad

I had a simple model imported into FreeCAD and I'd like to know the dimension of the bounding box for the model, how do I do that?

[image: Screenshot of a model in FreeCAD]

Comment: Not using FreeCAD, so not an answer: I like to use my slicer for that.